# How To add keywords for RSyntaxTextArea for syntax highlighting

Tags: java, swing

I am creating an editor, for which i have used RSyntaxTextArea. I want to some custom key words and auto completion to it.

Is there easy way to do it, or some other library which can be easy to implement.

Comment: *"Is there easy way to do it,"* Hire an expert on the component *"..or some other library which can be easy to implement."* ..asking for offsite resources is off-topic for SO. Don't forget to add ` '?' at the end of questions.

Answer (score 1):

Make a class that has a DefaultCompletionProvider as a field

```
DefaultCompletionProvider provider = new DefaultCompletionProvider();
```

Then make a method that adds your words to the provider

```
public void add(String word){
    provider.addCompletion(new BasicCompletion(provider, word));
}
```

After that add a small getter method just to return the provider

```
public CompletionProvider get() {
    return provider;
}
```

then

```
CompletionProvider provider = new YourClassName().get();
AutoCompletion ac = new AutoCompletion(provider);
ac.setAutoCompleteEnabled(true);
ac.setAutoActivationEnabled(true);
ac.setAutoActivationDelay(500);
ac.setShowDescWindow(true);
ac.install(Your RSyntaxTextArea object);
```